# Harmonic Oscillator propagator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator, path-integral, propagator

I'm reading the book on Quantum Field Theory by Anthony Duncan, and I'm a little lost with something of propagators.

He first define the propagator $K(q_f,T;q_i,0)$ as the amplitude of detecting a particle that initially was at $q_i$ at time 0 at another place $q_f$ at some time t, ie:

$$K(q_f,t;q_i,o) = <q_f | e^{-iHt} |q_i>$$

And then for the simple harmonic oscillator:

$$H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}mw^2 q^2$$

He says that the propagator satisfies the differential equation:

$$i \frac{\partial}{\partial t} K(q_f,t;q_i,0) = -\frac{1}{2m}\frac{\partial^2 K(q_f,t;q_i,0)}{\partial q^2_f} + \frac{1}{2}mw^2 q_f^2 K(q_f,t;q_i,0)$$

And I've no clue were that equation comes from. I'm guessing it's a Schrodinger like equation but $K$ is an amplitude not a state ket so I'm lost.

Does anyone has a clue?

Comment: From one perspective, you just ask how $\frac{∂}{∂t}\langle x|e^{At}|y\rangle=\langle x|Ae^{At}|y\rangle=A\langle x|e^{At}|y\rangle$ should be made sense of. Is the case without the term $\frac{p^2}{2m}$ clear?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65489/2451

Comment: Yes, now it's really clear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix element $\langle x |\psi\rangle$ where $x$ is allowed to vary is just the wavefunction

$$\psi(x) = \langle x |\psi\rangle.$$

So the matrix element $\langle x |p|\psi\rangle$ is just the wavefunction representation of the state $p|\psi\rangle$. We know that the momentum operator in the wavefunction representation acts as a derivative, so

$$\langle q_f |p|\psi\rangle = -i\frac{\partial}{\partial q_f}\psi(q_f).$$

Also $|q_f\rangle$ is an eigenstate of the $q$ operator (which is self-adjoint) so

$$\langle q_f |q|\psi\rangle = q_f \,\psi(q_f).$$

Now to show the differential equation you are looking for just take $|\psi\rangle=e^{-iHt}|q_i\rangle,$ and notice

$$i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\langle q_f|\psi\rangle = \langle q_f|H|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{2m}\langle q_f|p^2|\psi\rangle + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 \langle q_f|q^2|\psi\rangle.$$

Now apply the above identities twice.

Comment: I'd say the second equation with the derivative is not so evident, is it?

Comment: And whats the best way to solve the partial differential equation for the propagator K?

Comment: Well, it is the unique [fundamental solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Basic_examples:_propagator_of_free_particle_and_harmonic_oscillator) of the Schr eqn for the oscillator, with the canonical initial condition for the propagator (δ fctn for t=0) so you instantly get the Mehler kernel in a dozen different ways, as per WP article