# Dirac Delta in definition of Green function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, greens-functions, dirac-delta-distributions, correlation-functions, propagator

For a inhomogeneous differential equation of the following form
$$\hat{L}u(x) = \rho(x) ,$$
the general solution  may be written in terms of the Green function,
$$u(x) = \int dx' G(x;x')\rho(x'),$$
such that
$$\hat{L}G(x;x') = \delta(x-x') .$$

In this case, I don't have  difficulty in understanding why the above equality should be met.

However, in a homogeneous case,
$$\hat{L}u(x) = 0$$
the solution can be written using the propagator 
$$u(x) = \int dx' K(x;x')u(x')$$
that satisfies (according to books)
$$\hat{L}K(x;x') = \delta(x-x').$$

I am not able to understand this fact because, if you inserted $u(x)$, written in terms of the propagator $K(x;x')$, into this differential equation, you would expect $\hat{L}K(x;x')=0$.

This issue emerged during studies of the  Green function in many-body quantum mechanics, e.q. [Zagoskin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3319070487) or [Bruus, Flensberg](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198566336).

Comment: e.q. [Zagoskin](http://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Theory-Many-Body-Systems-Applications/dp/3319070487/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1443564118&sr=1-1&keywords=zagoskin) p.11 where $\hat{L} = i\hbar\partial_t - H(x,\partial_x,t)$

Comment: [This answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/20812/40502) might help to clear up your confusion.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your question has been answered [again](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/242689/why-is-the-propagator-the-greens-function-for-schrodinger-equation) and [again](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/20812/40502), and [again](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/65489/differential-equation-greens-function-satisfied-by-the-kernel-using-path-integ), albeit indirectly and elliptically--I'll just be more direct and specific. The point is you skipped variables: in this case, *t*, and so the expression you wrote 
("according to books, $\hat{L}K(x;x') = \delta(x-x')~$"), is nonsense, as you already properly found out; *unless* you included *t* in the generalized coordinates, but then again the convolution preceding it is not right.

It is all a deplorable misunderstanding, caused by sloppy language in the community. The [WP article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator) gets it right. The retarded Green's function *G* is the inverse of  $\hat{L}=i\hbar\partial_t-H$,
$$
\hat{L}G(x,t;x',t') = \delta(t-t')\delta(x-x')~,
$$
and it is *not exactly* the propagator. (Together with its advanced twin, they comprise a hyperformal unitary time evolution operator, of no practical concern here.)

Consider 
$$G\equiv \frac{1}{i\hbar} \theta(t-t') K(x,t;x',t'),
$$
and posit $K(x,t;x',t)=\delta(x-x')$. In that case, the propagator *K* 
turns out to be the *kernel* (null eigenfunction) of $\hat{L}$, simply because the time derivative in $\hat{L}$ acting on the step function $\theta(t-t')$, yields a $\delta (t-t')$ and hence a $\delta(x-x')$ when acting on *K* by the above posit. These then cancel the two deltas on the r.h.side, and leave only 
$$
\theta(t-t'\!) ~~ \hat{L}K(x,t;x',t') = 0
$$
behind.

So *K* is *the [fundamental solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_solution) of the homogeneous equation*, the real TDSE (recall you never wish to solve the inhomogeneous TDSE!);  and all works out.

Without loss of generality, take $t'=0$, so write $K(x,t;x')$. Consequently 
$$
\psi(x,t)=\int dx' K(x,t;x') u(x')
$$
is a null eigenfunction of $\hat{L}$ with initial condition 
$\psi(x,0)=u(x)$, which, in turn, justifies the posit.

That is, the above integral is the most general superposition of the fundamental solutions corresponding to all possible I.C.s

Illustrating the above with the free particle, 
$$
\left(i\hbar\partial_t + \frac{\hbar^2 \partial^2_x}{2m}\right) K(x,t;x')= 0
$$ 
yields 
$$
K(x,t;x')=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dk\,e^{ik(x-x')} e^{-\frac{i\hbar k^2 t}{2m}}=\left(\frac{m}{2\pi i\hbar t}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\frac{m(x-x')^2}{2i\hbar t}},
$$
which satisfies the I.C. posit.

You appear to have verified the solution of the above homogeneous equation already,
$$
\left ( i\hbar\left( -\frac{1}{2t} +\frac{m(x-x')^2}{2i\hbar t^2}\right) +\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left ( -\frac{m}{i\hbar t } - \frac{m^2(x-x')^2}{\hbar^2 t^2}   \right)   \right ) K =0,
$$
alright.

It is also straightforward to likewise find the propagator for the oscillator (quadratic potential), so then solve for the magnificent [Mehler kernel (1866)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehler_kernel),
$$
K(x,t;x')=\left(\frac{m\omega}{2\pi i\hbar \sin \omega t}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\exp\left(-\frac{m\omega((x^2+x'^2)\cos\omega t-2xx')}{2i\hbar \sin\omega t}\right) ~,$$
which, analytically continued,  precedes this QM problem by more than half a century...