# Why is the propagator the Green's function for Schrodinger equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, greens-functions, dirac-delta-distributions, propagator

Sakurai says (in various editions) that the propagator is simply the Green's function for the time-dependent wave equation satisfying

$$\begin{align}&\left [ -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \triangledown ''^2+V(\mathbf{x''})-ih\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\right ]K(\mathbf{x''},t;\mathbf{x'},t_0)\cr
=&-i\hbar\delta ^3(\mathbf{x''}-\mathbf{x'})\delta (t-t_0)\end{align}\tag{2.5.12/2.6.12}$$

with the boundary condition

$$K(\mathbf{x''},t;\mathbf{x'},t_0)=0\tag{2.5.13/2.6.13}$$

for $t<t_0$

I don't have any idea about where the $-i\hbar\delta ^3(\mathbf{x''}-\mathbf{x'})\delta (t-t_0)$ term comes from, and the propagator must be equal to zero when $t<t_0$.

Comment: ...and your question is? Just *compute* the propagator and plug it in there, you'll see it does indeed fulfill the equation (when you take the derivatives that are supposed to yield the distributions in the correct fashion).

Comment: I have computed and plug the propagator in the equation, but the result I got was 0, not $-i\hbar\delta ^3(\mathbf{x''}-\mathbf{x'})\delta (t-t_0)$.

Comment: Yeah, that's a common confusion. Do you know how the $\delta$ comes out for other Green's functions?  How the fundamental solution/Green's function gives the delta and not zero is really more a math than a physics question

Comment: I know given a linear differential operator $\mathfrak{L}$, a Green's function $G(x,s)$ is any solution of $\mathfrak{L}G(x,s)=\delta (x-s)$. But I still don't know the relation between the propagator and the Green's function.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20797/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22639/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65489/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint : Check if this "modified" Schrodinger equation is satisfied by the "modified" propagator
\begin{equation} 
\widetilde{K}(\mathbf{x''},t \;  \boldsymbol{;} \;\mathbf{x'},t_{0})=\theta(t-t_{0})\;K(\mathbf{x''},t;\mathbf{x'},t_0)
\tag{01} 
\end{equation}
where $\;\theta(t-t_{0})\;$ the unit step function with property
\begin{equation} 
\dfrac{\partial \theta (t-t_{0}) }{\partial t}=\dfrac{d \theta (t-t_{0}) }{d t}=\delta  (t-t_{0})
\tag{02} 
\end{equation}

Note that
\begin{equation} 
\dfrac{\partial \widetilde{K}}{\partial t}=\dfrac{\partial (\theta K) }{\partial t}=\theta\;\dfrac{\partial K}{\partial t}+K\;\dfrac{\partial \theta }{\partial t}
\tag{03} 
\end{equation}
and


<sup>\begin{equation} 
K\;\dfrac{\partial \theta }{\partial t}=K(\mathbf{x''},t \;  \boldsymbol{;} \;\mathbf{x'},t_{0}) \delta  (t-t_{0})=K(\mathbf{x''},t_{0} \;  \boldsymbol{;} \;\mathbf{x'},t_{0}) \delta  (t-t_{0})=\delta^{3}(\mathbf{x''}-\mathbf{x'})\delta  (t-t_{0})
\tag{04}
\end{equation}</sup>

Comment: But where does $\delta ^3(\mathbf{x''}-\mathbf{x'})$ come from?

Comment: @William Huang         $\dfrac{\partial \widetilde{K}}{\partial t}=\dfrac{\partial (\theta K) }{\partial t}=\theta\;\dfrac{\partial K}{\partial t}+K\;\dfrac{\partial \theta }{\partial t}$

$K\;\dfrac{\partial \theta }{\partial t}=K(\mathbf{x''},t \;  \boldsymbol{;} \;\mathbf{x'},t_{0}) \delta  (t-t_{0})=K(\mathbf{x''},t_{0} \;  \boldsymbol{;} \;\mathbf{x'},t_{0}) \delta  (t-t_{0})=\delta^{3}(\mathbf{x''}-\mathbf{x'})\delta  (t-t_{0})$

Comment: So the "unmodified" propagator satisfied $\left [ -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \triangledown ''^2+V(\mathbf{x''})-ih\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\right ]K(\mathbf{x''},t;\mathbf{x'},t_0)=0$ ?
And the "unmodified" propagator may be not equal to 0 when $t<t_0$ ?

Comment: Yes. See [related](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/209846/dirac-delta-in-definition-of-green-function/305182#305182), and check the elementary explicit examples.