# Green's function for the inhomogenous free particle time-dependent Schrodinger equation in 3D

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, greens-functions

I need to solve the equation
$$
\mathrm{i}\hbar \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial t}=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left(\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial z^2}\right)+ f(x,y,z,t)
$$
in the domain $t\ge 0$ with boundary condition $\Psi=0$ at $t=0$. Note that there is no $\Psi$ multiplying the $f$, it is not a potential problem. The function $f$ can be assumed to be square integrable and arbitrarily nice. The obvious thing to try is a Green's function, but when I try to write a Green's function for this in terms of functions of radius and time things get complicated. I cannot find a Green's function for this case anywhere, but I am sure that it must have been done. I would be very grateful if anyone could offer some advice or give a place to look.

This came up in study of the Schrödinger equation in noncommutative space time, and I specified the exact equation to be solved to minimize misunderstandings — it is a free particle equation (no potential) with inhomogenous forcing term.

Comment: I think you could go to the momentum frequency representation and find something like: $\Psi(\omega, k) = f(\omega,k) \left(\hbar \omega - \hbar^2 k^2/2m\right)^{-1}$

Comment: Related : [Why is the propagator the Green's function for Schrodinger equation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/242689/).

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/168783) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/168783) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 4):

If there were no "$i$" this would be the inhomogeneous heat equation.  In one space and one time dimension it would be
$$
\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}= \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}+f(x,t).
$$
The solution to this  involves the heat kernel
$$
G(x,t,\xi,\tau) =\theta(t-\tau)\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi (t-\tau)}} \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{4(t-\tau)}(x-\xi)^2\right\} 
$$
were $\theta(t)$ is the Heaviside step function.

With initial conditions $\psi(x,0)$ at $t=0$, the solution for $t>0$ is
$$
\psi(x,t)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty  G(x,t,\xi,0)\psi(\xi,0) \,d\xi
+ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left( \int_0^t  G(x,t,\xi,\tau)f(\xi,\tau)\,d\tau\right)d\xi.
$$
Your problem is  similar but the heat kernel needs to be replaced by the Schroedinger propagator. Hope this hint helps!

Answer (score 2):

**Green's function definition**
The Green's function is defined by equation
$$
\left[i\frac{\partial }{\partial t}+\frac{\hbar^2\nabla^2}{2m}\right]G(\mathbf{x},t;\mathbf{x}',t')=\delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}')\delta(t-t').$$
I also assume that we are looking here for a *retarded Green's function*, i.e.,
$$G(\mathbf{x},t;\mathbf{x}',t')=0\text{ for } t<t'.$$
(This bit is not crucial for the derivation below, but may be a of key importance, e.g., if using Fourier transform).

**Green's function of a Schrödinger operator**
There are exist many methods for solving the equationf or the Green's function. One method, that is useful to know, is the general expansion for the Green's function of a Schrödinger operator in terms of its eigenvunstions:
$$
\left[i\frac{\partial }{\partial t}+H\right]G(\mathbf{x},t;\mathbf{x}',t')=\delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}')\delta(t-t'),H\varphi_n(\mathbf{x})=\epsilon_n\varphi_n(\mathbf{x})\Rightarrow\\
G(\mathbf{x},t;\mathbf{x}',t')=\sum_n\varphi_n(\mathbf{x})\varphi_n(\mathbf{x}')^*e^{-i\epsilon_n(t-t')/\hbar}\Theta(t-t'),
$$
where $\theta(t-t')$ is the Heavyside step function:
$$
\Theta(t-t') \begin{cases}1, \text{ if } t>t',\\
0,\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
One can check that this expression is indeed the Green's function by substituting it to the defining equation.

**Solution**
In our case
$$\varphi_\mathbf{k}(\mathbf{x})\propto e^{-i\mathbf{k}\mathbf{x}},\epsilon_\mathbf{k}=\hbar\omega_\mathbf{k}=\frac{\hbar^2\mathbf{k}^2}{2m},$$
and the sum is replaced by an integral, so that we have
$$
G(\mathbf{x},t;\mathbf{x}',t')=\Theta(t-t')\int \frac{d^3\mathbf{k}}{(2\pi)^3}e^{i\mathbf{k}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}')-i\omega_\mathbf{k}(t-t')}
$$
The rest is math. For one, it is easier to carry out integration in polar coordinates, assuming that the z-axis is along $\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'$. The expression then becomes
$$
G(\mathbf{x},t;\mathbf{x}',t')=\Theta(t-t')\frac{-1}{(2\pi)^3}\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^\pi d\theta\int_0^{+\infty}dk k^2\sin\theta e^{ik|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'|\cos\theta-i\frac{\hbar k^2(t-t')}{2m}}
$$
Carrying integration over $\phi$ and $\theta$ gives
$$
G(\mathbf{x},t;\mathbf{x}',t')=\Theta(t-t')\frac{2}{(2\pi)^2|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'|}\int_0^{+\infty}dk k\sin\left(k|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'|\right)e^{-i\frac{\hbar k^2(t-t')}{2m}}=\\
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'|}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dk ke^{ik|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'|-i\frac{\hbar k^2(t-t')}{2m}}
$$
(In the second line I used the fact that the real part of $k\cos\left(k|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'|\right)e^{-i\frac{\hbar k^2(t-t')}{2m}}$ is an odd functiona nd gives zero, when integrated in symmetric limits $(-\infty,+\infty)$.)
The last integral is a Gaussian-like integral, and is easily calculated - if you are not at ease with Gaussian integrals, Gradshtein&Ryzhik give a formula (GR3.462-6):
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xe^{-px^2+2qx}dx=\frac{q}{p}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{p}}ee\frac{q^2}{p}$$
The final answer is therefore:
$$
G(\mathbf{x},t;\mathbf{x}',t')=i\Theta(t-t')\left(\frac{m}{2\pi i\hbar (t-t')}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\exp\left[-\frac{m(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}')^2}{2 i\hbar (t-t')}\right]$$

**Remark:** I urge you to go through the derivation, as I cannot guarantee that there have not been minor errors in my derivation, as well as typos.