# Reconciling special relativity and quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, hilbert-space, causality, propagator

I have been referring to [*QFT for the gifted amateur*](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Quantum_Field_Theory_for_the_Gifted_Amat.html?id=0rkVDAAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y), p. 75. To evaluate whether a particle can exist beyond its forward light cone, we check if it has a non-zero amplitude. The amplitude being referred to is just its wave function, right? I am a little confused because we evaluate the following quantity:
$$A = \langle x|e^{-i\hat{H}t}|x=0\rangle.\tag{8.16}$$
This looks like the expectation value of the time evolution operator between $x=0$ and some position, $x$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why has the expectation value of time evolution operator been taken to denote the amplitude?

Comment: @omnipotentcarrot05 Related Question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/471572/

Answer (score 0):

Amplitude $\langle x,t |x_0, t_0\rangle$ is probability amplitude from initial state $| x_0,t_0\rangle$ to final state $| x,t\rangle$, and its square represents probability. If we consider only positiom state as initial and final state, then time evolution factor is necessary. Now, $e^{-iHt} | x=0\rangle$ term is make sense.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful!