How is the Schrodinger kernel also a propagator?
Let $e^{-it\hat{H}/\hbar}$ be the time evolution operator for a Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$ and $K(x,t)$ its associated integral kernel, i.e.
$$\varphi(x,t) = e^{-it\hat{H}/\hbar}\varphi_0(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} K(x-y, t)\varphi_0(y) dy. \tag{1}$$
Since $K(x,t)$ is a fundamental solution (Green's function) to the Schrodinger equation, the time evolution of a state $\psi$ can be obtained by convolution with $K(x,t)$ as in (1). The important point here is that $K$ being written as $K(x-y, t)$ is a consequence of convolution.
In many physics textbooks they take this a step further and give physical meaning to $K(x-y, t)$. They state it is the probability of a particle going from $x$ to $y$ in time $t$. For example, in Sakurai's textbook he gives the formula
$$K(x'', t; x', t_0) = \langle x'', t| x', t_0 \rangle$$
where
$$K(x'', t; x', t_0) = \sum_a' \langle x'' | a'\rangle \langle a' | x'\rangle e^{iE_{a'}(t-t_0)/\hbar}.$$
In my notation Sakurai's result is:
$$K(x'', t; x', t_0) = K(x''-x', t-t_0) = \langle x'', t| x', t_0 \rangle.$$
I do not see what justifies $K(x-y, t)$, which originally appeared as a consequence of convolution, can be interpreted as a probability for a particle to go from $x$ to $y$ (after all the $y$ is only an integration variable that could've been chosen to be anything). I come from a background in mathematics and not physics so I find Sakurai's explanation very hard to follow.

@J.Murray That is what I would like to prove. I am starting with the fact that $K$ is a fundamental solution to the Schrodinger equation: $$\big(i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t} + \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\Delta\big)K = \delta$$ and nothing more to arrive at $K(x''-x', t-t_0) = \langle x'', t| x', t_0 \rangle$.

My question still stands - when you say you want to show that $K$ is a propagator, what does the word propagator mean to you?

@J.Murray I would define a propagator as $\langle x'',t | x', t_0\rangle$

@CBBAM $\langle x, t|y, t_0 \rangle=K(x-y,t-t_0)$ is the amplitude (and not the probability) to find the particle at the point $x$ at time $t>t_0$ if it had been at the point $y$ at time $t_0$.

@Hyperon From what I understand the amplitude should be an $L^2$ function, but isn't $\langle x, t|y, t_0 \rangle=K(x-y,t-t_0)$ a scalar?

@CBBAM In the equation $\psi(x,t)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dy K(x-y,t-t_0) \psi(y,t_0)$, the functions $\psi(x,t)$ (for $t$ fixed) are square-integrable (with respect to the variable $x$), but the integral kernel is a distribution, as e.g. $K(x-y,0)=\delta(x-y)$. I do not understand what you mean by "scalar".

@Hyperon I was interpreting $\langle x, t|$ and $|y, t_0 \rangle$ as states and so their bra-ket should be a scalar but I think it is incorrect to view it like this. Is this the idea?

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65489/2451 and links therein.
