# Single-particle Green's function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, greens-functions

Define a single-particle Green's function as
\begin{equation}
i\hbar G(xt;x't') = \langle x| e^{-iH(t-t')/\hbar} | x'\rangle.
\end{equation}
By inserting the completeness relation, we have
\begin{equation}
i\hbar G(xt;x't') = \sum_n \langle x|n\rangle \langle n| x'\rangle e^{-iE_n(t-t')/\hbar},
\end{equation}
where $|n\rangle$ and $E_n$ are the eigenstates and eigenvalue of the Hamiltonian $H$.
By using the Fourier transform, the Green's function in the energy domain can be calculated as
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
G(x,x';E) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} G(xt;x't') e^{iE(t-t')/\hbar} dt\\
&= \frac{1}{i\hbar}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left\{ \sum_n \langle x|n\rangle \langle n| x'\rangle e^{-iE_n(t-t')/\hbar} \right\} e^{iE(t-t')/\hbar} dt\\
&= \frac{1}{i\hbar}\sum_n \langle x|n\rangle \langle n| x'\rangle \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(E-E_n)(t-t')/\hbar} dt\\
&= -2\pi i\sum_n \langle x|n\rangle \langle n| x'\rangle \delta(E-E_n)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
However, from my knowledge, $G(x,x';E)$ is usually defined as
\begin{equation}
G(x,x';E) = \sum_n\frac{\langle x|n\rangle\langle n| x'\rangle}{E - E_n}.
\end{equation}
So my question is how can the above two equations be related? Or is there anything wrong with my derivation?

Comment: There are several kinds of Green's functions with different definitions. Your derivation seems correct, so I suspect you're confusing two different kinds of Green's functions up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct, but are different quantities.

The latter is the (Fourier transform of the) [retarded Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Non-relativistic_propagators) $G_R$. It is related to your "Green's function" (which really is a kernel) $G$ through

$$ G_R(x,t; x', t') = \frac{1}{i\hbar}\Theta(t-t')G(x,t; x',t') $$

See [this wonderful answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20797/differentiating-propagator-greens-function-correlation-function-etc) about kernels, propagators and Green's functions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. First of all, I forget a prefactor $i\hbar$ in my previous definition of the Green's function, which has been added. (Any way, it doesn't matter for the question). Besides, I also read the materials you cited, and agree with you that the problem come from the difference between retarded Green's function and kernel. However, I still cannot quite understand about these two quantities from that answer. Could you provide some other references to this concept? thanks so much.

Comment: @user8036269 This [question and the answer within](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22639/how-exactly-is-the-propagator-a-greens-function-for-the-schrodinger-equation) might shed some light on the matter.