# Can time-dependent Schrodinger equation be written in integral form?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, greens-functions

Can time-dependent Schrodinger equation be written in integral form using Green functions?

And if so, has it been applied in solving a particular problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How exactly is the propagator a Green's function for the Schrodinger equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22639/)

Comment: @Dvij D.C partial answer yes

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Non-relativistic_propagators