# Propagator as a Green's function in non-relativistic QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, greens-functions, propagator

I have a propagator

$$ K=\sum_k\langle x|a_k\rangle\langle a_k| y\rangle \exp\left\{ \frac{-iE_k(t-t_0)}{\hbar}  \right\} ~~,\tag{1}  $$

which I know satisfies the time-dependent Schrodinger equation

\begin{align}
i\hbar\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}K=\hat HK~~.
\end{align}

I am only interested in the retarded propagator so I multiply it by the Heaviside function $\Theta(t-t_0)$.  This enforces the condition that the probability density at time $t_0$ will diffuse only into the future.  Therefore, I solve

\begin{align}
i\hbar\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\Theta K&=\hat H\Theta K\\
i\hbar\left(K\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} \Theta + \Theta\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} K \right)&=\hat H\Theta K\\
i\hbar\, K\delta(t-t_0) &=\hat H\Theta K- i\hbar\,\Theta\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} K ~~.
\end{align}

Since the $\delta$-function picks out $t=t_0$, I can simplify $K$ on the LHS using (1) to write

\begin{align}
 \lim\limits_{t\to t_0}K&=\sum_k\langle x|a_k\rangle\langle a_k| y\rangle \exp\left\{ \frac{-iE_k(t_0-t_0)}{\hbar}  \right\} \\
&=\sum_k\langle x|a_k\rangle\langle a_k| y\rangle   \\
&= \langle x| y\rangle   \\
&= \delta^{(3)}(\vec x-\vec y)   ~~,
\end{align}

which yields

\begin{align}
i\hbar \,\delta(t-t_0) \delta^{(3)}(\vec x-\vec y) =\Theta \left(\hat H- i\hbar\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)K ~~.
\end{align}

Now I see that $K$ is the Green's function for the given linear operator.  However, in Sakurai's Modern QM, 3rd Ed. (p110), he has a minus sign on the $i\hbar$ on the LHS.  Where does it come from?

[This question is similar](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22639/) but does not explain where the minus sign comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem should be the equation
\begin{align}
i\hbar\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\Theta K&=\hat H\Theta K
\end{align}

Indeed if you start from
\begin{align}
i\hbar\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}K&=\hat H K
\end{align}
and multiply $\Theta$ on both side you have

\begin{align}
i\hbar\Theta\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}K &= \Theta\hat{H}K \\
 i\hbar\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}(\Theta K)-i\hbar\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}(\Theta) K &=\hat{H}(\Theta K) \\
-i\hbar \delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{y})\delta(t-t_0)=(\hat{H}-i\hbar \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t})(\Theta K)
\end{align}

Below is the result from the book Quantum field theory for the gifted Amateur Ch16 and $G^+$ is itself the retarded propagator which should be consistent with my argument.
[image]

Comment: Excellent.  I was wrong to assume that $\Theta K$ would also be a solution to the Schrodinger equation.  Thanks, you are a cool guy!

Comment: Actually, let me ask one more question.  If the propagator is supposed to be the Green's function, and the Green's function as you have it is $\Theta K$, then that must mean the sign does not matter.  Indeed, if the propagator is (like) a wavefunction, then the sign will go away when we square it to obtain some observable.  Therefore, I think the equation is correct as I have written it ***also.***  Do you agree?

Comment: I agree if we add a minus sign to the propagator then it's like multiplying a trivial phase to the state. $K$ should satisfy the Schrodinger equation so $(H-i\frac{\partial}{\partial t})K=0$. If $\Theta K$ also satisfy then we should also have $(H-i\frac{\partial}{\partial t})(\Theta K)=0$ but instead we have some $\delta$ function which is non-zero only at certain point. I think in your equation the RHS is not operating on $\Theta K$ so it's a bit different and not merely the problem of minus sign.

Comment: So then it's $\Theta K$ that is the Green's function, and not $K$?