# Are propagators in QFT Wightman Functions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, propagator, wightman-fields

I am studying relativistic quantum mechanics and I can't really understand how propagators arise from the theory.

They are generally defined as the Wightman function
$$
W_F (t',\vec{x}', t,\vec{x}) \equiv   \langle{0| \phi(t, \vec x) \phi(t', \vec x') |0}\rangle.
$$

I understand that the state $\phi(t, \vec x)| 0\rangle $ is the state representing an elementary particle of the field. The propagator gives us information about how two points $\vec x, \vec x' $ are related and also is a kernel so it can be solved using Green's functions. My question is: why are propagators Wightman functions? Are they supposed to be interpreted as the probability of transition between two points $\langle t, \vec x|t', \vec x' \rangle$? In what way is the Wightman function related to the probability of transition between two points?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20797

Comment: In that question the propagator is defined not derived, my question is regarding the interpretation of Wightman function as propagators, why is that justified?

Comment: Fair enough. I hadn't actually flagged it as a duplicate; consider it a related question for future readers who aren't as familiar with the term "Wightman function". You may find https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/273780 useful.